# How to pass variables to min and max functions in oracle?

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

The variable contains the name of the field. I want to pass it to the min function, not as a string but as a field

Comment: By _field_ do you mean "a name of a database table column" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the field is the name of a database table column, then you can do that using [Native SQL](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/native-dynamic-sql) . Here is an example for implementing that:

```
DECLARE
V_COL VARCHAR2(100) := 'COL_NAME';
V_STMT VARCHAR2(4000);
V_RESULT NUMBER;
BEGIN
V_STMT := 'SELECT MAX('||V_COL||') FROM TAB_NAME';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_STMT);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_STMT INTO V_RESULT;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_RESULT);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is with a case statement, e.g.

```
SELECT MIN(CASE v_col_name
           WHEN 'COL1' THEN COL1
           WHEN 'COL2' THEN COL2
           ...etc...
           END)
FROM tab_name;
```